# Generate doc only for some member functions

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a project which contains an RPC-invokable API. The project also contains some other code. I'd like to generate a clean documentation just for these API functions (for users working with the API). Yet it should still be possible to generate a documentation of the *whole* program, intended for the developers.

The API is split into several classes ("command modules"). First thing I did is tell Doxygen to only look at those files, of course. But these classes *also* have some code which is not part of the API I'd like to generate the documentation for (helper functions).

These invokable functions ("commands") have a special return type: `CommandResult`.

As an example, here is such an API class:

```
class CommandModuleFoo {
    int privateHelperFunction();
    int privateMember;

public:
    int publicHelperFunction();
    int publicMember;

public slots:
    /** Some documentation. */
    CommandResult myFunction1(int someArg);
    /** Some documentation. */
    CommandResult myFunction2();
};
```

Now the documentation should basically contain the following:

> ### class CommandModuleFoo
>
> ---
>
> **Public members:**
>
> - `CommandResult myFunction1(int someArg)`
>
>   Some documentation.
> - `CommandResult myFunction2()`
>
>   Some documentation.

**Question:**

I know that I can select only a subset of the project's files by simply just naming them in the `INPUT` variable of my `Doxyfile`. But can I also select only a set of functions using a pattern?

Since I guess this is not possible, can I tell Doxygen to only generate documentation for one section? Doxygen has section markers: `\if`...`\endif` can be used to **exclude** some part of the document but include them with the configuration variable `ENABLED_SECTIONS`. But I need the opposite. Is there something like `ONLY_SECTION`?

**Possible workarounds:**

- I could use above-mentioned section conditions around every code *except the commands I want to document*. But that sounds very ugly.
- I could set `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS` to `YES` in order to only generate documentation for documented members, but that would make it impossible to generate also a full documentation of the program, if one wants to. (i.e. it forbids to document non-API functions). Also, detecting undocumented API-functions is then more difficult.

I currently use the second workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Use [`\internal`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal) in the documentation of internal functions (the non-commands in this case):

  ```
  /**
   * \internal
   * This helper function does foo.
   */
  void myHelperFunction();
  ```

  Your commands use normal doxygen comments:

  ```
  /**
   * Some documentation.
   */
  CommandResult myFunction();
  ```
- Then, in your Doxyfile use [`INTERNAL_DOCS = YES`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_internal_docs) if you compile the documentation of the whole program and `INTERNAL_DOCS = NO` (default) to compile your API documentation.

Basically, treat your program like it was a library. Library developers often encounter this problem: they obviously want to have a clean documentation for the users of the library which only contains exported stuff, while they (probably) also want to have a more verbose documentation for developers of the library.

PS. You can also use `\internal` to selectively include paragraphs of the documentation of a function, i.e. your documentation for the developers could include some more detail which is not important for the users of your API. For details consult [the documentation of `\internal`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal).